Why my flutter track recording app can't run in background?

I am new to the flutter, currently I am handling a flutter project that users can use the google map and geolocator to track down their commuting tracks, however what's the problem is that when I use AVD to simulate, or when I build APK to try out IRL, both can not track down when the app is not resumed(e.g.: While the device stands by or when user is using other apps or on the desktop, etc.), namely, the app would just line up the location before temp leaving the app and the location after resuming.
Here's the tracking log I designed in the same file.
See the Time jumps from 12 to 44 and the location remains the same till the google map itself detect the new spot.

I think this may not be the code's problem while it works well when the app is activating.
I've added several method to AndroidManifest.xml like these:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!--ForegroundService-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>

However, I am not sure where went wrong, the app just can't running in background as I've imagined.
The timer can run normally in background in AVD environment, however, it can't when the app is installed into my phone, and, the tracking method can't run in background in both environment.
I don't really know where to fix up or to add some more functions.
I've searched several method to try out like flutter_isolate or flutter_background_service, these may seem to be a good way to solve my problem, however, I tried but maybe in wrong way or else, it didn't work out.
Like I tried this:
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch(state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      // Optionally, stop the service or just stop the tracking.
        print("App is resumed");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        // Stand by
        print("App is paused");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        // temp leave
        print("App is inactive");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
      // No need to handle this state for most apps
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
        break;
    }
  }

to detect whether the app state is inactive or paused, then I put designed functions to store up the location info and the independent time, but it didn't workout while when I leave the app temprorarily, it just stop working in anyways.
I really need to figure out how it works, thanks to anyone that's gonna answer this problem, I am willing to provide more what I've done in this project.

To keep your app running smoothly in the background, you'll need to dive into native code and leverage "https://pub.dev/packages?q=pigeon" for smooth communication between Flutter and the device. Keep in mind that Flutter packages  (flutter_background_service etc.) may not always play nice due to different device behaviors – for instance, Techno phones tend to restrict background operation. Redmi devices might need battery optimization permissions. And on iOS, running in the background isn't possible.

Is that true that I gotta edit some Swift and Kotlin to make my flutter project work in background? If so, then flutter is kinda complicated tbh, I am not sure if there is other ways to execute my method simpler.

Yes you need to edit some code in kotlin/java for android to create background or foreground services. But in iOS it's not possible to always keep running an app in background.
